# How to ensure that a user can only click like button once for each post?

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze

I want to add a like button.If a user clicks on like button ofa particular post the number of likes of that particular post should increase by 1.However if he clicks again on the like button of the same post the number of likes should decrease by 1.

In my code the user can give more than 1 like to each post.How to change that?

Javascript code is:

```
 Template.postItem.events({    
'click button':function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            var documentId = this._id;

            this.likes=this.likes+1;
            console.log(this);
            Posts.update({ _id: documentId },{$set:{likes:this.likes}});
            }


            });
```

HTML code:

```
<template name="postItem">
    <li>
    {{_id}}
    <h4>{{name}}</h4>
    <i>Posted by {{postedBy}} on {{createdAt}}</i>
    <br>
    {{likes}}<button class="btn btn-default glyphicon glyphicon-hand-up" >Like</button>
```

Here {{button}} is a helper of postItem which returns the value of the number of like on each post.

Comment: You need to store a flag for each user for each post to be able to tell if the user has voted already.

Comment: @Thilo How can I do that?

Comment: Maybe `Likes.insert( {_id : documentId + "_" + userId })`. Then you can check if such a document exists or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can have in the Posts document a variable "likes" as an array containing the IDs of users who like the post.

```
Post = {
   likes: [String]
}
```

And you can check if the specific user already like the post.

```
var Post = Posts.find({_id: documentId, likes: Meteor.userId()});
```

Documentation for mongo: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-documents/#match-an-array-element

Comment: That requires an update to the document if it is being liked, and it does not scale well to a large number of users.

Comment: @Thilo I think if you don't have 50M likes/min I could do the job.
You have to save their IDs somewhere, to check if the user already like the post.